# Is it possible to register to the redraw event in Blender?

Tags: python

I would like to run a script before the 3d viewport is redrawn. I know its possible to register to "Frame changed" events using

```
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(myfunc)
```

but is the same possible for a redraw?